# How to get the Authentication Provider for actions-on-google on Node using account linking with Auth0?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have Javascript App running under Node v8.11.2 which uses the Actions-On-Google library. I'm using the V2 API. I have account linking set up with Auth0 and am using the SignIn helper intent. Auth0 is set up to use Google, Facebook and Twitter.

The scopes I use are OPENID, OFFLINE_ACCESS, PROFILE and EMAIL.

Everything is working fine and when the User is authenticated I get an Access Token returned.

My question is, how do I get the Authentication Provider that was selected by the User so that I can use the Access Token correctly to retrieve profile elements such as the display name, email address etc??

The *signin* object passed to the Sign In Confirmation intent handler just contains the following regardless of the provider selected: -

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValue","status":"OK"}
```

Any help greatly appreciated as I have a deadline and this is driving me a bit crazy now!

Thanks,

Shaun

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to get the required information when you have your accessToken available then you could use what is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669486/9428536).

In node this looks like that:

```
let link = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="+accessToken;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        request(link,(error, response, body) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                let data = JSON.parse(body);
                let name = data.given_name ? data.given_name : '';
                conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
                    speech: "Hello "+ name + "!",
                    text: "Hello "+ name + "!"
                }));
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log("Error in request promise: "+error);
                resolve();
            }
        })
    })
```

Everything you need should be in the data object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rémi, thanks for replying. My problem is to work out if the user authenticated through Google, Facebook or Twitter for example in Auth0 so that I can make the required call to obtain the user's email and name. The snippet you've given me will help with doing that for Google. Think I'm going to have to raise this with Google.

Comment: Ok, sorry I've never done it with Facebook or Twitter so I can't really help you on that. Good luck!