# How to make the chatbot redirect a unknown answer to my email so I can manually answer the problem?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I’m new to Dialogflow and I want to make a chatbot for faq and troubleshooting. I want the chatbot to send me responses that I do not know how to answer so I can manually contact the people whose problems have not been solved. How do I achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you will have different intents for your FAQ system, so that if user asks a question it will be matched to specific intent and bot will send a response according to that matched intent.

Now if none of the intents matched, it will go to **Default Fallback Intent** where you ca enable the **webhook**. In the webhook, you can write a function to send email yourself with the user query and other user details so that you can check and reply to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you could have your endpoint recognise that the fallback intent has been triggered, but you will also need to obtain the users email which is outlined here [Get email from user using Google actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086605/get-email-from-user-using-google-actions) , otherwise you wont be able to get back to the user with a response.